# I want to render a attribute of a class (which is a class) with my how doc

Tags: python, class, python-sphinx, autodoc

```
class Parameters(dict):
     """ Some doc here """
     pass

class System(object):
     Parameter = Parameters
     """ The default parameters attribute builder """

     def __init__(self):
         self.parameters = self.Parameters()
```

The problem is when i do a `autoclass` of System with sphinx, the document Parameter will not be what I wrote bellow `Parameter = Parameters` but will be the full doc of the Parameter class. I do not want that, it is too messy and do not match what my .Parameters attribute is really (can be a Parameters class but also a function, or a `dict(a=0,b=1).copy` etc...) .

```
System
======
.. autoclass:: system.System
    :members: __init__,Parameters
```

The only way I found is to set Parameters to None first and change it at init but it is not convenient for other reasons

```
class System(object):
    Parameter = None
    """ The default parameters attribute builder """

 def __init__(self):
     if self.Parameters is None:
         self.Parameters = Parameters
     self.parameters = self.Parameters()
```

Comment: When I do this, it creates [this](https://i.imgur.com/ILGy48l.png), which seems like what you want. Also, since it is an attribute, it should really be `parameter = Parameters`, since CamelCase is reserved for class names.

Comment: Differing Sphinx versions, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

can it be done, like this ?

```
class Parameters(dict):
    pass

class System(object):

    def __init__(self, Parameters):
        self.parameters = Parameters


parameters = Parameters()
parameters['x'] = '3.14'
parameters['y'] = '1.618'

system = System(parameters)

print(system.parameters)

{'y': '1.618', 'x': '3.14'}
```

Comment: hello, thanks,  my problem is only with the sphinx doc render. in my programs the Parameter attribute must be a constructor of parameters defined in subclassing and should not be an argument os 'System'. e.g. : `Parameters = dict(x=3.14, y=1.618).copy` in a System sub-class definition.

Comment: Sorry, got it !